# Как цитировать текст, написанный с ошибками?

Tags: грамотная-речь, цитата

Как цитировать текст, написанный с ошибками и/или опечатками? Их можно исправлять при желании, или тогда это уже нельзя будет считать цитатой?

Comment: Тоже интересует данный вопрос. Вообще насколько знаю, тексты писателей (например) цитируют так, как есть, сохраняя орфографию автора.

Comment: Приятно это. :) Одно дело какие-то вольные знаки препинания, мне кажется, которые ещё в какие-то рамки укладываются, а другое дело — несомненные ошибки.

Comment: Согласна. В данный момент делаю к.р. по текстам великих русских писателей, так вот постоянно ошибки в пунктуации и орфографии. А в текстах современных авторов вообще их куча.

Comment: Да, к сожалению (про современных).

Comment: Анна, в текстах великих русских писателей не ошибки,это орфография того времени.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в цитате есть ошибки или опечатки, то как правило цитируют вместе с ними, но дают примечание, что орфография авторская. Если опечатка или ошибка затрудняет восприятие текста, то в квадратных скобках делается расшифровка Например, "исчо [*еще*]".

Это делается для того, чтобы если вы неверно интерпретируете ошибку, читатель смог бы восстановить оригинал.

Comment: А это относится к лишним или отсутствующим пробелам? Их тоже нельзя добавлять при отсутствии после знаков препинания или убирать, если их не меньше двух подряд? Или к непоставленной точке в конце предложения?

Comment: Лишние пробелы убирать вполне допустимо, так как это цитату не искажает, а вот если их надо добавить, то лучше привести авторский вариант, мало ли это сделано специально или разделить слово нужно не так как вы решили

Comment: Я имел в виду в добавление пробела после точки, запятой, двоеточия, отделение тире запятыми. При этом никакие слова не разделяются. ;))

Comment: Правки технического характера, не меняющие смысл цитаты вполне допустимы.

Comment: Отлично! Вот это я и хотел узнать и надеялся получить как раз такой ответ. :)